# AddressBook Counting Birthday entries from all records

Tags: ios, addressbook, abrecordcopyvalue

I am attempting to count the total number of Birthday entries throughout the Address Book.

### Problem line

```
/*  This line crashes only when using kABPersonBirthdayProperty  */
ABMultiValueRef lBirthdays = ABRecordCopyValue(lRef, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);

/*  Note that when this line is changed to another `ABPropertyID`, it works fine.
    Only seems to crash on NSCFDates.
 */
```

There is more code to iterate through all of the Contact throughout the entire Address Book, but is irrelevant to this Question.

```
int totalBirthdayEntries = 0;

CFIndex lContactBirthdayCount = ABMultiValueGetCount( lBirthdays );

for (int births = 0; births < lContactBirthdayCount; births++)
{
    totalBirthdayEntries++;
} 

NSLog(@"Total Birthdays in Address Book: %i",totalBirthdayEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe kABPersonBirthdayProperty will give you a CFDate/NSDate, not an ABMultiValueRef. Try this:

```
CFDateRef date = ABRecordCopyValue(lRef, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
```

Comment: @WrightsCS Can you show more of your code and more info about the crash?